# How to solve MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Index.Js File:**

```
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const helmet = require("helmet");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const userRoute = require("./routes/user")
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth")

dotenv.config();


//Mongoose Connect

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err) =>
{
    console.log("mongdb is connected");
});

//middleware

app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("common"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Welcome to home page");
})

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/user", userRoute);

app.listen(5000,function(err)
{ 
    if(err)
        console.log("Server not connected")
    console.log("Connnection is established");
})
```

**Auth.Js File**

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require('../model/Users');


//REGISTER

router.get("/register", async (res,req)=> {
    const user = await new User({
        username: "gauravnegi",
        password: "123456",
        email: "gauravnegi@gmail.com",
    });

    await user.save();
    res.send("ok");

});


module.exports = router;
```

Error:

```
return callback(new error_1.mongoservererror(res.writeerrors [0] ))
```

**Full Error Snippet:**

[image: Click to view full error]

How to resolve above error?

Comment: Your `User` schema (which you forgot to add to your question) defines a field `description` which is set to `unique` when it shouldn't be. After changing your schema you will also need to remove the unique index for that field from your database manually, Mongoose won't do that automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear it is not a server side error it's a client side error b/c you have defined somewhere some field `{unique:true}` in your model! So you should wrap your function inside `try-catch` block for example

```
router.get("/register", async (res,req)=> {
 try{
    const user = await new User({
        username: "gauravnegi",
        password: "123456",
        email: "gauravnegi@gmail.com",
    });

    await user.save();
    res.send("ok");
 }catch(error){
  //check if it was a duplication error
 if(error.code==11000) // show user that it is unique path
 and handle other validation error
}
    

});
```

Comment: This certainly is a server side issue, the `description` field of the `User` model is set to `unique` when it shouldn't be.